# Errbit error in Rails test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I am a newbee in rails. While executing test code I am getting the following error

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/airbrake-ruby-1.4.4/lib/airbrake-ruby.rb:102:in `configure': the 'default' notifier was already configured (Airbrake::Error)
from /home/akhil/test-prjct/ver3/prjct/config/initializers/errbit.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:652:in `block in load_config_initializer'
```

**config/initializers/errbit.rb** has following code

```
 Airbrake.configure do |config|
  config.host = 'https://192.168.2.143:3000'
  config.project_id = -1
  config.project_key = '***********'
  config.environment = Rails.env
  config.ignore_environments = %w(development test)
end
```

Please help me to solve the issue. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, issue was not created by errbit. I am using **mailboxer** gem , which has mailboxer folder in lib folder of the project. I found that it is not needed for my project and so I deleted that which resolved my issue

Answer (score 0):

You have a duplicated configuration for Airbrake. When you install it, it creates `config/initializers/airbrake.rb` by default. Just remove this file and will work fine.

You can edit this file /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/airbrake-ruby-1.4.4/lib/airbrake-ruby.rb

Add this code after line 98 in configure method:

```
puts "Configuring Airbrake"
puts caller[0]
puts "*" * 99
```

And then look in logs for this text. You will find out where configuration method is called from.

Comment: has no airbrake.rb file

Comment: So you must have some another file with configuration for Airbrake. This error is displayed when you already configured Airbrake

Comment: @AkhilSudhakaran I've updated my answer with info how can you find where config method is called from. Hope it will help

Comment: I removed the entire code in errbit.rb .Now routing some routing error.

Comment: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:555:in `add_route': Invalid route name, already in use: 'root'  (ArgumentError)
You may have defined two routes with the same name using the `:as` option, or you may be overriding a route already defined by a resource with the same naming

Comment: But in route.rb there is only one one route for root. When I comment it, the error moves to next route

Comment: It kind of looks like every file in your app is loaded twice. But at this point I can't help

Comment: Its actually running, but while testing it shows this errors

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121815/discussion-between-akhil-sudhakaran-and-michal-mlozniak).